# RedShift - CSV load with line Break

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl

Im trying to load a CSV file while loading I got the error

> Delimited value missing end quote

**CSV file Error line**

[image]

**REDSHIFT ERROR:**

```
line_number     | 13
colname         | Comment
col_length      | 250
raw_line        |"123"|"123"|"xyz"|"2009-06-25 21:00:14.660000000"|"0"|""|""|""|""|""|"HI,

raw_field_value | HI, 
err_code        | 1214
err_reason      | Delimited value missing end quote
```

Comment: Please Edit your question to show the COPY command that you are using. Specifically, are you using the `REMOVEQUOTES` option?

Comment: Seems to be repost of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45415262/398670

Comment: @John - I tried REMOVEQUOTES , but  still getting the same error

Comment: @Craig - In my previous post, it doesn't have a line break

Comment: Its fixed by regenerate CSV (via bcp) with -k

Answer (score 4):

You could use CSV option in COPY command. Don't use REMOVEQUOTES or ESCAPE with it. CSV handles everything so in my opinion it's the best solution.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-csv

Comment: Literally, you saved me! This helps a lot! `FORMAT AS CSV` worked

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to escape the newline characters in the source data and then specify the `ESCAPE` option in your `COPY` statement. Please have a look at ["Preparing Files for COPY with the ESCAPE Option"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_preparing_data) for more details.